# How to trap Grails Spring-Security BasicAuth failures?

Tags: grails, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have a RESTful Grails (2.2.1) web-app with the Spring-Security plugin (1.2.7.3) configured for BasicAuth on all controllers (it is a "service app" with JSON payloads and has no HTML output).  When authentication fails (bad userid/password/account locked), the response body is an ugly Tomcat HTML-formatted string.  I would prefer to generate my own (JSON) response, but cannot seem to intercept the exception before it is handed to Tomcat.

I have tried configuring `adh.errorPage` and `failureHandle.defaultFailureUrl`, but these controller/actions never seem to be invoked.

What do I need to configure to be able to do this?

Edit: some additional settings from `Config.groovy`:

```
...filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/error/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-basicAuthenticationFilter,-basicExceptionTranslationFilter',
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter' ]
...adh.errorPage = '/error/denied'
...controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [ '/error/**': ['permitAll'] ]
...failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = '/error/authfail'
```

and, of course, I have an `ErrorController.groovy` with the above methods defined.

Also: I have an ApplicationListener defined to count failed logins, and I noticed it is being invoked twice for a single REST call - could the redirect to the Error controller be failing authentication as well?

Edit2: my supposition was correct: "/grails-errorhandler" was failing auth after the initial failure. I don't know if this is the proper way to do it, but now I have:

```
...filterChain.chainMap = [
                '/<each controller listed separately>/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter']
]
```

and don't seem to need any `controllerAnnotations.staticRules`(??) and things seem to work!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what is being returned I can only assume the 403 (forbidden) is being returned to your client. In that case you can always map that response code to your own controller to return the correct JSON message. For example

### grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy

```
class UrlMappings {
  static mappings {
    "403" (controller: "error", action: "forbidden")
    "404" (controller: "error", action: "notFound")
    "500" (controller: "error", action: "internalError")
  }
}
```

Further information about mapping, response codes, and such can be found in the [documentation for URL Mappings](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings).

Comment: Actually, it is a 401 "not authorized".  However, I have tried adding the above mappings, but they are never invoked.  See my edit for additional info.